# Why Asynchronous Javascript Get Request No Response?

Tags: javascript, get

i'm having problem to use HTTP.Get request on Javascript,
here is my code

```
function getData(url, callback) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                callback(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

why no response when i call it

```
getData("http://www.example.com/data.php",   function(data) {            
     console.log(data);
});
```

Can you please help me? any hint would be very helpful

Comment: You likely have an unsuccessful response, i.e., a response with a different status code than 200. If this is the case, `callback` will never be called (since the `if` condition would be false). You can see if this is the case in the Network tab of the developer console of your browser.

Comment: at a guess, it'll be a CORS problem

Comment: @Frxstrem it's status is 200

Comment: @JaromandaX how to deal with it sir?

Comment: get the server to allow cross origin resource sharing

Comment: so the problem is server doesn't support cors? @JaromandaX

Comment: That's a guess. You have to determine if it's a CORS issue yourself, because clearly you are not trying to get `http://www.example.com/data.php`

Comment: but i want to get `http://www.example.com/data.php` do you have the right way how to get it? @JaromandaX

Comment: `http://www.example.com/data.php` returns status 404 - there's ONE problem already - it doesn't issue CORS headers, that's TWO problems

Comment: the status is `0` when i print `this.status` @JaromandaX

Comment: if status is 0 when readystate is 4, that's a classic CORS issue

Comment: @JaromandaX i fix it by adding this extension to chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the hint.

Comment: oh god, that extension is opening up your chrome browser to a world of hurt - good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is surely because browser prevented cross domain call.

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/data.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Adding headers to request will not work until the Server or Site honours this header.

Why don't you create/host your on service in your domain which then on server side makes HttpRequest to example.com/data.php and provide you the desired response.

Your page > Gives ajax call to your service > Gives http get call to data.php.

Comment: Yes, that should be the answer, i didn't know that. The guy that answer me never tell me.